# String sets commutative under concatenation

Tags: formal-languages

If $A$ and $B$ are languages over the same alphabet $\Sigma$, what can we say about $A$ and $B$ if $AB = BA$? Is there some way to characterize all languages with this property?

Answer (score 2):

Let $\Sigma$ be a finite alphabet. Given regular languages $A,B \subseteq \Sigma^{\ast}$ we want to solve $AB = BA$, which means every word $uv \in AB$ with $u \in A, v \in B$ has a prefix in $B$ and a suffix in $A$, i.e. we have $uv = yx$ for $y \in B$ and $x \in A$.

Now I guess your are looking for necessary and sufficient criteria on $A$ and $B$ such that the equation $AB = BA$ holds. I can only give you partial answers.

i) First note that if $A,B$ form submonoids, i.e. we have $A^2 \subseteq A$ and $B^2 \subseteq B$ and both contain the empty word, then
$$
 AB = BA \Leftrightarrow (AB)^2 \subseteq AB
$$
i.e. $AB$ forms itself a submonoid. For the proof note that if $AB = BA$ then $(AB)^2 = A^2B^2 \subseteq AB$, and conversely as $B \subseteq AB$ and $A \subseteq AB$ we have $BA \subseteq (AB)^2 \subseteq AB$, and for sets of words
we have $BA \subseteq AB$ iff $BA = AB$ (I give a proof below).

ii) For the more general case lets try to use [Levi's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi%27s_lemma) and for language $U,V \subseteq \Sigma^{\ast}$ set
$$
 U^{-1}V := \{ w \in \Sigma \mid \exists u \in U : uw \in V \} \quad 
 UV^{-1} := \{ w \in \Sigma \mid \exists v \in V : wv \in U \}
$$
i.e. words that remain if we take away initial segments from $U$ or suffixes from $V$. Than Levi's lemma states that
$$
 uv = xy \Leftrightarrow ( \{u\}^{-1}\{x\} \cap \{v\}\{y\}^{-1} ) \cup ( \{x\}^{-1}\{u\} \cap \{ y\} \{v\}^{-1} ) \ne \emptyset.
$$
So generalising we may set for $A,B \subseteq \Sigma^{\ast}$
$$
 L := A^{-1}B \cap AB^{-1}.
$$
Then we have that if $B \subseteq LA$ and $AL \subseteq A$ then $AB = BA$. For a proof suppose that $uv \in AB$ with $u \in A, v \in B$, and assume $v = wx$ with $x \in A, w \in L$. Then $uv = uwx$ and with $uw \in A$ we have $AB \subseteq BA$. Now this assumption is quite strong, and I do not think that a converse holds.

Note that I do not used regularity of $A$ and $B$, and I have no idea how to use it, beside maybe that $AB = BA$ is a decidable question then as we can construct automata for their concatenation and test if they accept the same language.

*Appendix*: For languages $A,B \subseteq \Sigma^{\ast}$ we have $AB \subseteq BA$ iff $AB = BA$. For each fixed $n$ in $AB$ and in $BA$ there are the same number of words of length $n$, as there is an easy bijection $uv \mapsto vu$ for $u\in A, v \in B$. So $AB \subset BA$ gives $AB \cap \Sigma^n \subseteq BA \cap \Sigma^n$ for each $n$, hence $AB \cap \Sigma^n = BA \cap \Sigma^n$. As these finite sets partition $AB$ and $BA$ the result follows.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is related to famous problem formulated by Conway [1, p. 55 and 124] in 1971. Given a regular language $L$, is the largest language commuting with $L$ also regular?

However, in a famous breakthrough paper, Kunc [3] gave the most negative possible answer to Conway’s problem by showing that there exists a finite language $L$ such that the greatest solution of the equation $XL = LX$ is co-recursively enumerable complete.

This contrasts with the fact that the largest solution of the inequality $XK \subseteq LX$ is regular provided that the language $L$ is regular, as proved in [2].

[1] J. H. Conway, Regular Algebra and Finite Machines, Chapman and Hall, London, 1971.

[2] M. Kunc, [Regular solutions of language inequalities and well quasi- orders](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/271538/1-s2.0-S0304397505X06089/1-s2.0-S0304397505005384/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEKj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICqgfUDihPJRBDYod%2Fvpsi6m1LPEIppWR8zPhqiPKE7%2BAiEA36ky8apNNlsXOhPPfES12tovJnrkUfOjLr5Hgh38rMAq%2BgMIMRAEGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDDUlcNQ1W80ldwVazyrXA%2BNRKHAzzx8sgGQt1fKP6CptFAWxFaaEo%2FhHg6bzWCDZSV1Z4vDudfkqq8Nmue9jLHmyyHfHG9d666ReiTxXrA6oY2FeQGnx7XT%2BoEa5QWO6s3qE5xHbgk35xWXk3SDKlW1ODBfIDVmUJ8zp8zcq2cKKUYiJsTHb%2FIomaH61sYPl3hVEN8%2F0u3Ebs1xswDwNohDRY8YUmxEATCimckjbELqbkpZyKNWnZ5UgOIZreMu7rUgbqKpWPXeUpLeoYb%2B2eWwqtZW6JluJOfqM%2FzgtifL7y9wQcVLjLJiJ1zqVo3XiIFl41znG%2Bt4wDojYPqqnnJAJoS5%2BhvW7U4b%2FOsiyPMMhQTp7%2Fdx3e0xwq0wsnjQM2wg6G4HkB0UEByrVId2ABV8RRI4JEX%2BFaz4I8jEgEH%2FajO2DGerXpF4WRuJwSl%2FQlvfwTsU3V7JfhpX5y%2BqL2xVt3Od49xr5pCtNGYm%2B3xuzsteTm16%2FJf27HpRqszDrQ1ByV2Mhfh2L6fCJhUeYNVLs6YMy3Ga%2B%2Fnf%2BiXq533TjS1jfksD7jOVu4W%2FQcc%2Bp1ptRPyff0AdNzw%2BNXzdPylapbW1hGcbhLu9e98g7JaQxh%2BWz68Bho5J85cMdhrzKVyZRq3dsJzDf1%2BeRBjqlAS3KCIEkmg1gj8bbXVCmj2Gnhp%2FJmrR07T8tLBJJpdtDMpwCbTaOchESFybt55VjGOjqsfaPYFJ8%2F8CO4%2Bm%2F3I4%2BSfWNRcI1mWS%2FP6diUtCdoz13CaGMj47JPIiSThdbDpjC0nGjk02%2BgzWAMgbO7rz4CT1KSbXWXNv0BKJSt75UKt49Pq9q5qWsb8OPm7iZn6vMtCaX5CA3inpYajQMqVE460nNPg%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20220322T162502Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYQBSZSGCK%2F20220322%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=847f8d38cf57697fb897da2865bc61b5fad6a0400dda5b7440aadfdce4091233&hash=40ef6750aaabeb6922bd3f5ac831a4e410c003018456e2045bf1a32a7452b5d2&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=S0304397505005384&tid=spdf-750177b6-d366-4a15-9336-82bed0997ae2&sid=cb4a78fb7eb2d04f642ac4e08273c735d031gxrqb&type=client&ua=53015451575107035001&rr=6f0047ec6c2d0820). *Theoret. Comput. Sci.* **348**(2–3) (2005) 277–293.

[3] M. Kunc, [The power of commuting with finite sets of words](http://www.math.muni.cz/%7Ekunc/math/commutativity.pdf), *Theory Comput. Syst.* **40**,4 (2007), 521–551.